# Is there a way to set an SQL comment from an IQueryable?

Tags: nhibernate, iqueryable, icriteria

`ICriteria` has `SetComment()`, but I see nothing comparable for `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate 5+ there is `WithOptions` extension method that allows to set some query specific options like timeouts, cache options, and comments.

```
var query = (
    from e in session.Query<YourEntity>()
    select e
).WithOptions(o => o.SetComment("Your comment"));
```

You might need to import `NHibernate.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll have to upgrade to NH5, I think, to try this out.  Maybe later this week...